# If $\omega$ is non real cube roots of unity , then the eigenvalues of the matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, complex-numbers, linear-transformations, determinant

> If $\omega$ is a non-real cube root of unity, then what are the eigenvalues of the matrix
>
> $$\left[ \begin{matrix}
> 1 & 1 & 1\\
> 1 & \omega & \omega^{2} \\
> 1 & \omega^{2} & \omega^{4}
> \end{matrix}\right]
> \left[
> \begin{matrix}
> 1 & 0 & 0\\
> 0 & -1 & 0\\
> 1 & 0 & 0
> \end{matrix}\right]
> \left[ \begin{matrix}
> 1 & 1 & 1\\
> 1 & \frac{1}{\omega} & \frac{1}{\omega^{2}}\\
> 1 & \frac{1}{\omega^{2}} & \frac{1}{\omega^{4}}\end{matrix}\right]?$$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Hint:* The matrix is of the form $B=PAQ$. Note that $PQ=3I$. Therefore, $B=P(3A)P^{-1}$ and so $B$ and $3A$ have the same eigenvalues.

Comment: I have to compute product of these three matrices And diagnol elements of resultant matrix are eigenvalues. Is there any shorter way to find eigenvalue

Comment: @sejy, you *don't* have to compute the product of these three matrices: similar matrices have the same eigenvalues.

Comment: OK thanks eigenvalues of 3 A i.e. 3,-3,0 are eigenvalues of product of these three matrices